# Wrapper function for template<> in C++

Tags: c++, c, templates, wrapper, name-mangling

I am currently trying to create a wrapper interface that can translate C++ to C, and while studying on the possibilities to do that, I came across the template functions (and classes). Knowing that these functions can take any data type and return any data type as well, I find it hard to create a corresponding caller function name that C could read. A simple example is the adder.

```
template <class typesToAdd>
typesToAdd addStuff(typesToAdd a, typesToAdd b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

My interface includes the `extern "C"` command to avoid the C++ name mangling in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use function templates to simplify both implementing and maintaining the actual code that does the work but to provide a C interface, you'll still need to explicitly instantiate the functions for the types you aim to support.

If you'd like a C++ user to have the same restricted access to the functions as a C user will have, you can move the template implementation into the `.cpp` file and do the explicit instantiation there. A C++ user trying to use the function with types for which you have not explicitly instantiated the template will get a linking error.

It could look something like this:

```
// a.hpp
#pragma once

template <class T>
T addStuff(const T& a, const T& b); // no implementation here.
```

```
// a.cpp
#include "a.hpp"
#include "a.h"

template <class T>
T addStuff(const T& a, const T& b) {
    T rv = a;
    rv += b;
    return rv;
}

// C interface - note: it's inside the .cpp file
extern "C" {

int add_ints(int a, int b) {
    return addStuff(a, b);
}

double add_doubles(double a, double b) {
    return addStuff(a, b);
}

}
```

```
/* a.h */
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int add_ints(int, int);
double add_doubles(double, double);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

A C user can now include the `.h` file and call the two functions for which you've provided an implementation.

Example:

```
// main.c
#include "a.h"

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", add_ints(10, 20));
    printf("%f\n", add_doubles(3., .14159));
}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ -c a.cpp
gcc -o main main.c a.o
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution!!! Why do you use the `auto` keyword in `auto rv = a`?

Comment: @PolarBear You're welcome! Oh, the `auto` just happened. :) `T` would be equally fine. I changed that now and added header guards.

Comment: ... and a small usage example

Comment: What happens with implementing this example is that the C gives an error for not using pointer types.

Comment: @PolarBear I get no such errors and I compile both with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors`. What compiler and flags do you use?

Comment: Sorry it was from a previous copy where I added the pointer. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222373/discussion-between-polar-bear-and-ted-lyngmo).

Answer (score 3):

Template is not a function that works for any data type. It is a template for a function that is created at compilation time. Each type you use creates a new function with a new symbol in the binary.

To export to C, you will have to specialize the type you want to use from C, like:

```
template <class typesToAdd>
typesToAdd addStuff(typesToAdd a, typesToAdd b) {
    return a + b;
}

extern "C" {

    int addStuffInt(int a, int b) {
        return addStuff(a, b);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes true, but in this way there is no point to use a template function if I am bound to using only one data type. Previously I was suggested to do an _"explicit instantiation of each type"_ which frankly speaking I also don't know how to do or what that means.

Comment: In this case, I have implicitly instantiated it for `int`. Does not change much, you will have to specify every type you want to use from C. And yes, doesn't make much sense. And the fact that there are things that can be done in C++ but not in C is precisely why people use C++ instead of C.